# How to create a table in MySQL from the sql dump of a table taken from other database instance?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, rdbms

I'm using MySQL via PHPMyAdmin.

I've exported one table from one database instance in MySQL.

Now I want to create the same table with the data into another instance of MySQL database from that downloaded sql dump.

Can I create it? If yes, how? If no, why?

Comment: what do the innards of the script tell you about `create` or `if not exists create` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to import the dump into your database this could be done from the terminal using

```
mysql -u<username> -p<password> <database> < <dump.sql>
```

assuming your dump file contains a `CREATE TABLE` query and then the associated data from the table or that the table already exist in the database.

You could also do this from phpmyadmin.

1. First select your database
2. Click the `import` button
3. Select the file you would like to import by clicking `File to import`
4. Finally click `Go` to start your import

Comment: It's possible for the SQL file to include a ``USE `foo` `` line which would tell MySQL to import the SQL to the database `foo` regardless of what database you specified through phpMyAdmin or at the command line. If such a line exists, you can edit and remove it with any plain text editor.